# Got any tips or tricks for Terminal in Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, terminal, macos

One tip or trick per answer.

My favorite is

```
open .
```

Opens the folder you're currently browsing in Finder. You can also pass URLs, images, documents or else to `open`.

If you specify a program name with -a you can pass the URL, image, document or folder to that program instead, e.g. `open -a Preview image.png`, overriding the default program set for the filetype.

Please don't post duplicates. Search in the question like this: `inquestion:this ls -l`

**Mac OS X specific** answers only.

Comment: There is a similar thread on Server Fault as well: http://serverfault.com/questions/7346/useful-commandline-commands-on-mac-os

Comment: Didn't check SF, but that would seem to be more focused on server commands people find useful.

Comment: You can use `open` for everything: URLs, images, documents. I use it everyday.

Comment: As an extension to that:

  open -a Mail filetosend.ext

Creates a new Email with the file attached.

Comment: How is opening the folder you're currently browsing useful? `open .` seems redundant, given you... already have it open.

Comment: @Nick Bedford: It's very useful.  For example, I use the command line to scp a bunch of files down from the server.  Then, I use "open ." to open the current folder up in the finder, where I can easily right-click on a file and say "open in excel".

Comment: @Nick Bedford: If you have the folder open in Terminal, `open .` opens it Finder. It's useful if you want to do something graphical.

Comment: If you don't want the file to open in the default application you can re-direct it to the application of your choice with the -a <appname> flag.

Comment: There's a lot of ***not* Mac OS X specific** answers, which is a requirement outlined in the question. Should the answers be revisited or the question edited?

Comment: @koiyu: OS X is based on FreeBSD, so anything that works on both is acceptable.

Comment: @Troggy the question you posted has been removed.

Comment: I'd love to see this closed or migrated back. No accepted answer, and in reality - the number of tricks in terminal is effectively unlimited. If each answerer could take their great answer and think of a valid question - think of all the high quality questions and then answers we would have on this site.

Comment: Some interesting answers under http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/24326/8546

Comment: What is meant by `inquestion:this ls -l` ..where do I type that in to search this question for all of the commands?

Answer (score 180):

You can hold option and click a position in the current line to move your cursor to that position.

Comment: Nice, never knew about this one. Very handy.

Comment: This also allows you to select and copy rectangular sections from Terminal.

Comment: :D I voted this up and forgot about it, so I was thinking "Wow! This is cool, I need to upvote this!" and then I saw that I already had. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't know if I'm happy or angry right now...

Comment: I don't get it :(  how is this different then click on a line with my cursor without holding anything?

Comment: @Glide - did you try that, you'll find that doesn't work in a terminal.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the visual line, not the whole command. Still better than nothing, though. I guess if I were desperate, I could shrink my font size and/or max out width of the window.

Comment: Wow, this is great! But why on Earth didn't they make a normal click do this, without holding option? It's not like a click by itself does anything else...

Comment: I was dreaming of this for a long time, how could I know it needs Option key?.. Awesome, the future is here :)

Answer (score 179):

`pbcopy` and `pbpaste`:

```
# Copy output of command to clipboard
grep 'search term' largeFile.txt | pbcopy

# Abuse clipboard contents
pbpaste | sed 's/ /%20/g'

#  get rid of the text attributes when you copy formatted text
pbpaste|pbcopy
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, great answer!

Comment: I'm guessing "pb" stands for "pasteboard"?

Comment: @Nocturne: Precisely.

Comment: Doesn't this only work with the developer tools installed?

Comment: @Mark Thalman: No - pbcopy and pbpaste are located in `/usr/bin` and have been included as part of the OS since at least 10.4.

Comment: this works great for sharing vim pasteboard

Comment: +1. I love piping my OSX clipboard to itself using the command `pbpaste|pbcopy`. This will get rid of the text attributes when I copy formatted text. I saved it as a service and under a keyboard shortcut (F5)

Answer (score 170):

`opensnoop` is my new favorite utility.  It uses DTrace to show you all of the files that are being accessed on your system, you need to execute it with superuser privileges

```
sudo opensnoop
```

You can also watch what a particular process opens by passing in the PID:

```
sudo opensnoop -p PID
```

Or watch a particular file to see who's opening it:

```
sudo opensnoop -f /etc/passwd
```

Comment: +1. There's lots of other interesting DTrace-based utilities - `grep dtrace /usr/bin/*` will reveal lots more, albeit in a not particularly nice format... Also, Instruments (part of the Developer Tools) is a GUI frontend to lots of this functionality (there's an "opened files" instrument)

Comment: What's wrong with good ol `lsof` ?

Comment: Josh: lsof does a snapshot of open files. opensnoop is monitoring a live process. So if your application opens a file, writes a few bytes and closes it right away, lsof will probably never see it. opensnoop will.

Comment: In addition to dbr's comment about `grep dtrace /usr/bin/*` being unpretty, I have a better idea: `grep -l dtrace /usr/bin/*`, list only the filenames that match, no file content (read: binary garbage) when doing this.

Comment: What's wrong with good ol `fs_usage`?

Comment: `man -k dtrace` is also useful; most if not all of these utilities have `man` pages.

Answer (score 152):

It's not built in but this is the most effective way to get my wife to stop using my laptop to read celebrity news for hours after 4–5 requests to get my Macbook back:

```
echo 'The system is overheating and needs to go to sleep now.' | \
growlnotify -a 'Activity Monitor' 'OVERHEATED'; \
sleep 1; \
say 'Overheated system.'
```

Since it's almost always around 70c it's believable.

Comment: +1 Hilarious. Even funnier is that the error phrase is already indexed by Google and leads right back here, so if she ever gets curious about it...

Comment: I've got Growl installed, but I get "-bash: growlnotify: command not found". What's wrong?

Comment: It's an add-on: http://growl.info/documentation/growlnotify.php

Comment: You could append `;sleep 30 && :(){:|:&};&` and make it all the more convincing....

Comment: can anyone share a 1 line install for growlnotify?

Comment: @Brian Armstrong: `brew install growlnotify` (assuming you have [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) installed)

Comment: Depending on your version of `growlnotify`, you might need `-m` before your message: `growlnotify -a 'Activity Monitor' -m 'OVERHEATED'`

Comment: Your picture isn't working.

Comment: @daviesgeek Yeah it was free image hosting and it's gone now. I don't have the original. Note that this was 2 years ago.

Comment: I got an error when I tried to use `growlnotify`: `Got disconnected: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain ...`, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: For osx 10.8 and 10.9 i suggest https://github.com/alloy/terminal-notifier

Answer (score 130):

Start a quick webserver from any directory:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Comment: I made a bash function for this, with a default port value: serve() {
  python -m SimpleHTTPServer ${1:-8080}
}

Comment: This is the greatest thing in the world.

Comment: I *think* this is cool.  But how do I let others use it?  I have to open up my fire wall, and then point them to my IP?  How do I do these?

Comment: @John: Open a new question.

Comment: I guess simpleHTTPServer should also display details like
'Your ip is 10.1.3.3' and prompt if you want to disable firewall if it has to be amazing

Comment: @John e.g. use a relay like PageKite or Yaler

Comment: i had issues with the Python server so use a node equivalent now: https://github.com/75lb/local-web-server

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not OSX specific ..

Answer (score 129):

When you're editing a particularly long and gnarly command line: 
 <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> will pop you into your editor and let you work on it there.

Comment: That is very handy.

Comment: How to abort if you have typed in something that you don't want to run?

Comment: @neoneye: just remove what's in your editor and save & close the file. Or simply ^C if you've not ^X^E already.

Comment: I knew you could switch between emacs and vim modes in BASH, but this is even handier than that.  My absolute favourite tip so far.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I use terminal but with zsh as the shell, so maybe that is why.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for posting this. This is a bash feature, so it'll work anywhere you have bash. (Also explains why it doesn't work  in zsh.)

Comment: Anyone know how to make this work for zsh?

Comment: @slomojo: use something like this in your zsh config

`# Bash-like command editing
autoload -U edit-command-line; 
zle -N edit-command-line; 
bindkey '^X^e' edit-command-line;
`

Comment: Any way to have it open in vim instead of emacs?

Comment: @Jeff just set the environment variable EDITOR to vim

Comment: @Slomojo It seems to be setup for you on zsh if you are using the oh-my-zsh package.

Comment: working fine on my zsh with oh-my-zsh

Answer (score 103):

The `say` command invokes the system text-to-speech capabilities.

```
say "Hello there."
```

Comment: Oh yes. I use this one to let me know something is done -- "scp remote.com:some_file /tmp; say 'file copy done' "

Comment: I use it to freak people out. SSH into my neighbors mac and say random things.

Comment: Can be useful if you're locked outside of your apartment :) http://xkcd.com/530/

Comment: I don't use "say" at the command line the way Doug Harris does (although I'll have to start!), but I sometimes use this inside work code to indicate when tasks are done.  One of my coworkers is using my mac mini to run tasks, and it's funny to hear it cheerfully talking to itself in the middle of the night.

Comment: You can add a -v parameter to specify which voice to use, I'm not in my mac right now, but I'll post the list when I get there.

Comment: Here's the voice list in 10.6.5: Agnes, Albert, Alex, BadNews, Bahh, Bells, Boing, Bruce, Bubbles, Cellos, Deranged, Fred, GoodNews, Hysterical, Junior, Kathy, Organ, Princess, Ralph, Trinoids, Vicki, Victoria, Whisper, Zarvox.  Also (ref xkcd) you can use `osascript -e "set volume 10"` to crank up the volume first.

Comment: [How to prank a mac](http://redditlurker.com/funny/Post/t3_1g1uo8)

Comment: For people who were curious about how Apple wants you to say OS X, try out `say "It's pronounced OS X, not OS x"`

Answer (score 100):

```
!!
```

Runs the last command again. Great for tracking changes.

Comment: especially useful when you forget to run a command as root: `sudo !!` (almost makes me want to yell "SUDO!!" as loud as possible)

Comment: Something similar is 
    `!$`
which takes the last parameter:
    `ls foo*`
followed by 
    `rm !$`
to safely delete, etc.

Comment: @Gazzer: I prefer hitting M-. (or is it Alt-.) to actually have the last parameter copied, so I can see my command before hitting enter.

Comment: Similar to Gazzer's comment, there is also `!^` to retrieve the first parameter.

Comment: `watch`is not bad too for tracking changes ;)

Comment: `!! make me a sandwich` [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/149/)

Comment: sudo bang bang quick summary http://shadabahmed.com/blog/2013/08/16/bang-bang

Answer (score 97):

Stop using the arrow keys and navigate the command line more quickly with

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>: moves to the start of the line

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>: moves to the end of the line

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>: move back one character

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>: move forward one character

<kbd>esc</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>:  move back one word

<kbd>esc</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>: move forward one word

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>: delete from the cursor to the beginning of the line

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>: delete from the cursor to the end of the line

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>: delete from the cursor to the beginning of the current word

Comment: If only it supported VI style input...

Comment: `set -o vi`, then hit escape as usual to switch to command mode.  `bash` uses `readline`, which has a vi mode.

Comment: In Preferences → Keyboard you can assign these to shift/option + arrow keys.

Comment: These are "emacs" keybindings used by libreadline, and they're almost all available in any text box widget in OSX

Comment: Note that `Esc, b` and `Esc, f` (back/forward one word) are bound to `Opt-b/f` (when you set the terminal to recognize `Opt` as `Meta`)

Comment: option-left and option-right will move back/forward one word, also

Comment: is there a delete one previous word? (In windows, I would do ctrl+delete)

Comment: ctrl+w will delete the previous word.

Comment: Ctrl+u even works when terminal echo is turned off.

I like to use it when I botch a password when prompted by SSH, the passwd utility, or really anything that takes a password from the prompt.  It's much more reliable than hammering backspace and hoping you deleted all of the characters.

Answer (score 91):

`mdfind` to use spotlight from the command line - really really really handy! Finds things in every directory as well, so it's more useful when looking for files that are part of the system.

`mdfind -live` updates in real time, which again is incredibly handy.

Comment: And `mdfind -name`, which finds only matching filenames (instead of all files that contain the search text).

Comment: `locate` and `updatedb: aliased to sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` is not bad too ;)

Answer (score 88):

```
cd -
```

Will restore the previous directory you were in. Very handy if you accidentally type `cd` alone without any arguments and end up in your home directory.

Comment: Not Mac OS X specific, but very cool.

Comment: If you think that's cool, look into pushd and popd. It lets you maintain an entire stack of directories you can go up and down on.

Comment: Don't forget that `cd -` also works like pushd/popd... ie. want to go to the 4th cd ago? `cd -4` etc.

Answer (score 88):

Open a man page in Preview:

```
pman () {
    man -t "${1}" | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app
}
```

Open a man page in TextMate:

```
tman () {
  MANWIDTH=160 MANPAGER='col -bx' man $@ | mate
}
```

Open a man page in SublimeText:

```
sman() {
    man "${1}" | col -b | open -f -a /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime\ Text\ 2
}
```

Quit an app cleanly from the command line

```
# Quit an OS X application from the command line
quit () {
    for app in $*; do
        osascript -e 'quit app "'$app'"'
    done
}
```

Relaunch an app from the command line:

```
relaunch () {
    for app in $*; do
        osascript -e 'quit app "'$app'"';
        sleep 2;
        open -a $app
    done
}
```

Uninstall an app with AppZapper from the command line:

```
zap () {
    open -a AppZapper /Applications/"${1}".app
}
```

Comment: On the first one, I use ps2pdf (part of ghostscript) to convert the postscript, otherwise preview does the conversion and asks you to save the result on close, so its like this:  man -t $* | ps2pdf - - | open -g -f -a /Applications/Preview.app

Comment: `pman` could be enhanced by using `man -t $@` instead of `man -t "${1}"`, so it supports specifying the manual section too.

Comment: you can define this commands at .bash_profile to be able to use them at all times

Comment: Relevant, although not a command line trick: Read local man pages in Safari using `man:grep` style urls with http://bruji.com/bwana/

Answer (score 61):

You can drag a folder from the finder to the terminal and it will paste the full path to that file.

```
cd <drag folder to terminal>
```

This is basically the opposite of *open* in the terminal

Comment: D&D is also very usefull for files to be used as parameters

Comment: You can also drag the folder icon that is in the title bar of a finder window to a terminal window.

Comment: Was just going to add that - the folder icon in the title bar is a proxy for the folder itself, you can drag it from there to anywhere (like to a "select file" dialog window, Terminal, etc.)

Answer (score 52):

Here's something nice and pointless:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine -background &`

Runs your screensaver as your desktop wallpaper. Useless but cool.

This does not affect normal operation of the screensaver, but will end after normal screensaver has been activated, either by timeout or by moving the mouse to a predefined hot corner.

Alternatively, you can use:

```
killall ScreenSaverEngine
```

Comment: To disable this, press `Ctrl` + `C` or just close the Terminal window.

Comment: or kill -9 then the process number that is spit out. Should look something like [1] 12345. 12345 is the process number.

Comment: This is great for Quartz Composer animations!

Comment: Android's "live wallpaper" comes to the Mac

Answer (score 48):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>: Go to the beginning of the line and to the end of the line.

This also works in every Cocoa text input!

Comment: You can also use other emacs keybindings: ctrl-b, ctrl-f (forward or backward one); ctrl-k (kill from position to end of line); ctrl-y (paste previously killed text); ctrl-p, ctrl-n (up or down in command line history), and more.

Comment: This binding is very common - works in Pico and Nano as well.

Comment: Great, I didn't knew about this, it's pretty handy!

Comment: You guys need to learn about emacs! (since thats where all these keybindings come from...)

Comment: I think Mac OS X was written using Emacs. :)

Comment: emacs - Escape Meta Alt Control Shift ;)

Answer (score 41):

(Assuming we're looking for Mac OS X specific tricks.)

I've got an alias to launch quicklook on a file from the command line:

```
$ type -a ql
ql is aliased to `qlmanage -p 2>/dev/null'
$ ql photo.jpg
Testing Quick Look preview with files:
    photo.jpg
```

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>: Kill it and return to the prompt.

Comment: On a similar note, `qlmanage -r` can be used to reset Quick Look and regenerate previews and stuff.

Comment: On a related note: in Terminal, typing Command-Period will issue a Control-C.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  Typing [space] will also cause the preview to go away.

Answer (score 37):

```
$ emacs -batch -l dunnet

Dead end
You are at a dead end of a dirt road.  The road goes to the east.
In the distance you can see that it will eventually fork off.  The
trees here are very tall royal palms, and they are spaced equidistant
from each other.
There is a shovel here.
>
```

Comment: Darn. Now how do I pick up the shovel?

Comment: `take shovel` or some variant.

Comment: Never mind, awesome tip!

Comment: When I found out about this I wasted a half a day playing it!

Comment: damnit emacs!!!

Comment: Spoiler alert: http://members.multimania.co.uk/szunvukung/texts/dunnet.txt

Comment: I've never really played any of these games before, so imagine my surprise when... `>eat shovel \ You forcefully shove a shovel down your throat, and start choking. \ You are dead. \ You have scored 0 out of a possible 90 points.`

Comment: >shake tree
`You begin to shake a tree, and notice a coconut begin to fall from the air.
As you try to get your hand up to block it, you feel the impact as it lands
on your head.
You are dead.
You have scored 0 out of a possible 90 points.` ... probably should have seen that coming.

Comment: @Dan Ha ha! ROTFLOL!

Comment: Don't forget `M-x tetris`

Answer (score 36):

afconvert allows you to convert from and to all audio formats internally known to Core Audio.

e.g., converting an aiff file to 160kbps AAC:

```
afconvert track.aiff -o track.m4a -q 127 -b 160000 -f 'm4af' -d 'aac '
```

Answer (score 34):

Quickly check what is eating all your memory:

```
top -o vsize
```

And for your CPU

```
top -o cpu
```

<kbd>Q</kbd> to quit

Comment: I didn't want to make a whole answer for this, so.. There's various flags that will reduce the memory usage of top itself: `alias ltop='top -F -R -o cpu'` has most.. If you specify `-o vsize` etc, it will override the `-o cpu`.

Comment: You can also use `-u` instead of `-o cpu`. `top -u` sorts by CPU usage.

Answer (score 32):

To make <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> useful again, that is going a word forward or backward like they usually do on Linux, you must make Terminal.app send the right string to the shell. In the preferences, go to the `Settings` tab and select your default profile. Go to `Keyboard` and set `control cursor left` and `control cursor right` to send string `\033b` and `\033f` respectively.

While your're at it, you can also fix <kbd>Home</kbd> (`\033[H`), <kbd>End</kbd> (`\033[F`), <kbd>Page Up</kbd> (`\033[5~`) and <kbd>Page Down</kbd> (`\033[6~`) so that they send those keys to the shell instead of scrolling the buffer.

Comment: as suggested Slomojo: back/forward one word are bound to Opt-b/f when you set the terminal to recognize Opt as Meta

Comment: Well, some people do actually need the option key… On many keyboard layouts, characters like `{}[]` requires a key combination involving [⌥]. Or if you use the US layout and needs some non-english characters on a regular basis (like I do with Umlauts) you also need [⌥].

Answer (score 30):

Resample image so height and width aren't greater than specified size, e.g. 100x100:

```
sips -Z 100x100 image.jpg
```

sips supports other operations such as: flip, rotate, crop, image properties query, colour profile query and modification. Check `man sips` for usage.

Answer (score 27):

http://github.com/joelthelion/autojump - "cd" that learns.

Comment: [*z is the new j*](https://github.com/rupa/z)

Answer (score 25):

With `hdiutil` you can easilly mount a disk image:

```
hdiutil mount ~/Desktop/lastest_webkit.dmg
```

Dismounting (hacker way):

```
hdiutil detach `df | grep WebKit | perl -pe 's@^/dev/([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*@$1@'`
```

Dismounting (easy way):

```
hdiutil detach /Volumes/<mountpoint>
```

or take the easier approach (that **churnd** suggested below):

```
hdiutil detach /Volumes/latest_webkit
```

Comment: Just do "hdiutil detach /Volumes/<mountpoint>"

Comment: Aren't the last two choices the same?

Comment: I've used `diskutil` for much of this lately, after learning (and hating) disktool. `diskutil eject /Volumes/backups` has been a frequent use lately.

Comment: I'm not sure why but `/sbin/umount /Volumes/Foo` seems to work faster than hdiutil

Comment: I mostly use diskutil too, specially `diskutil verifyVolume <volume name>`, since the Verify function in Disk Utility for RAID volumes specifically, never worked (long standing bug).

Answer (score 25):

Some useful aliases:

```
alias ..="cd .."
alias ...="cd .. ; cd .."

alias ls="ls -G" # list
alias la="ls -Ga" # list all, includes dot files
alias ll="ls -Gl" # long list, excludes dot files
alias lla="ls -Gla" # long list all, includes dot files

alias stfu="osascript -e 'set volume output muted true'"
alias pumpitup="sudo osascript -e 'set volume 10'"

# Get readable list of network IPs
alias ips="ifconfig -a | perl -nle'/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/ && print $1'"
alias myip="dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com"
alias flush="dscacheutil -flushcache" # Flush DNS cache

alias gzip="gzip -9n" # set strongest compression level as ‘default’ for gzip
alias ping="ping -c 5" # ping 5 times ‘by default’
alias ql="qlmanage -p 2>/dev/null" # preview a file using QuickLook

# Upload image to Imgur and return its URL. Get API key at http://imgur.com/register/api_anon
imgur() { curl -F "image=@$1" -F "key=ANONYMOUS_IMGUR_API_KEY" https://api.imgur.com/2/upload | egrep -o "<original>.+?</original>" | egrep -o "http://imgur\.com/[^<]+" | sed "s/imgur.com/i.imgur.com/" | tee >(pbcopy); }
```

All of these are in my `~/.bash_profile` so I can use them in every Terminal window.

P.S.

```
alias chpwn="chown"
```

For more, see [my dotfiles repository on GitHub](http://mths.be/dotfiles), and/or [view my `.osx` file for OS X-specific preferences and settings](http://mths.be/osx).

Comment: +1 - Excellent answer. I particularly like aliases ips/myip!

Answer (score 22):

`textutil` is a very handy tool that can cross convert text between HTML, RTF(D), Word (including XML), OpenOffice.org Writer, and the webarchive format.

I use it, notably, in a service that converts the selected text to HTML, uploads it to a server then imports it into Instapaper.

Comment: This is BSD specific, I believe, not just OS X. But useful nonetheless...

Comment: @Henno, nope; 10.8.5 (at least) has `textutil` as well. The manpage for `textedit` states that it supports "txt, html, rtf, rtfd, doc, docx, wordml, odt, or webarchive".

Answer (score 22):

Make files invisible:

`SetFile file -a V`

SetFile can change a lot of other file attributes and metadata, as well.

SetFile is not a OS X native command it comes bundled with DevTools/Xcode.

If you don't have Xcode and don't want to download about 6 GB, you can use

```
sudo chflags hidden|nohidden <file/folder>
```

chflags is a BSD command and it also has a Man Page just enter this in Terminal

```
man chflags
```

for those who don't like to enter commands self and just would like to know what there stands in the man. Here you have:

```
CHFLAGS(1)        BSD General Commands Manual           CHFLAGS(1)

NAME
     chflags -- change file flags

SYNOPSIS
     chflags [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] flags file ...

DESCRIPTION
     The chflags utility modifies the file flags of the listed files as speci-
     fied by the flags operand.

     The options are as follows:

     -f      Do not display a diagnostic message if chflags could not modify
         the flags for file, nor modify the exit status to reflect such
         failures.

     -H      If the -R option is specified, symbolic links on the command line
         are followed.  (Symbolic links encountered in the tree traversal
         are not followed.)

     -h      If the file is a symbolic link, change the file flags of the link
         itself rather than the file to which it points.

     -L      If the -R option is specified, all symbolic links are followed.

     -P      If the -R option is specified, no symbolic links are followed.
         This is the default.

     -R      Change the file flags for the file hierarchies rooted in the
         files instead of just the files themselves.

     -v      Cause chflags to be verbose, showing filenames as the flags are
         modified.  If the -v option is specified more than once, the old
         and new flags of the file will also be printed, in octal nota-
         tion.

     The flags are specified as an octal number or a comma separated list of
     keywords.  The following keywords are currently defined:

       arch, archived
           set the archived flag (super-user only)

       opaque  set the opaque flag (owner or super-user only).  [Directory
           is opaque when viewed through a union mount]

       nodump  set the nodump flag (owner or super-user only)

       sappnd, sappend
           set the system append-only flag (super-user only)

       schg, schange, simmutable
           set the system immutable flag (super-user only)

       uappnd, uappend
           set the user append-only flag (owner or super-user only)

       uchg, uchange, uimmutable
           set the user immutable flag (owner or super-user only)

       hidden  set the hidden flag [Hide item from GUI]

     As discussed in chflags(2), the sappnd and schg flags may only be unset
     when the system is in single-user mode.

     Putting the letters ``no'' before or removing the letters ``no'' from a
     keyword causes the flag to be cleared.  For example:

       nouchg  clear the user immutable flag (owner or super-user only)
       dump    clear the nodump flag (owner or super-user only)

     Unless the -H or -L options are given, chflags on a symbolic link always
     succeeds and has no effect.  The -H, -L and -P options are ignored unless
     the -R option is specified.  In addition, these options override each
     other and the command's actions are determined by the last one specified.

     You can use "ls -lO" to see the flags of existing files.

EXIT STATUS
     The chflags utility exits 0 on success, and >0 if an error occurs.

SEE ALSO
     ls(1), chflags(2), stat(2), fts(3), symlink(7)

HISTORY
     The chflags command first appeared in 4.4BSD.

BUGS
     Only a limited number of utilities are chflags aware.  Some of these
     tools include ls(1), cp(1), find(1), install(1), dump(8), and restore(8).
     In particular a tool which is not currently chflags aware is the pax(1)
     utility.

BSD              March 3, 2006                 BSD
```

Comment: That's in `/Developer/Tools`, which you'll have to download from Apple's site (heavy), or install from the OS disc.  No system is complete without it.

Comment: `chflags hidden`?

Comment: You prefix a flag with "no" to remove it. So it's `sudo chflag nohidden <file/folder>`, not `show`.

Answer (score 19):

```
 dot_clean .
```

This one isn't an every day usage - but it was a big time saver once - 
I had a SMB fileserver (Avid Unity) that was displaying lots of .filename files for mac users as well as PC users.

This cleaning command totally fixed the problem (after running twice)

Comment: its great to finally know theres a good way to do this.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what ._* files are and how this program fixes the described problem, man page didn't help a lot, could you please give more details? Is it completely safe to use?

Comment: ._ files are invisible in the Finder in Mac OS - but are visible to other operating systems. They also tend to be a relic to 'resource forks' that went out of use as the mac transitioned from OS 9 to OS X. Instead of just throwing them out willy nilly in another OS - you can ask the Mac OS to help you clean out unnecessary ones using the dot_clean command.

Answer (score 17):

`history` shows a list of the recent commands you've run — something like 500 or 600 commands.  I frequently use `history | grep something` to find a command i've used recently.

Comment: That's a bash builtin, not OS X specific.

Comment: True. Sorry. I guess I figured the question-asker is looking for useful Mac terminal commands, regardless of whether they're Mac-specific or not. If I was mistaken, sorry.

Comment: You can press Ctrl+R in bash to interactively search through your shell history. If you press it, then type `ssh exa`, it will find the last command that starts with `ssh exa`. You can press ctrl+r again to cycle further backwards, return to execute the current command, or press escape to further edit the command

Comment: While we're at it, `history -a; history -r` copies history between terminal tabs.

Comment: Once you've run `history` you can run any item from the resulting list by using the history item's number. e.g. `!23` will run item 23 in the history list.

Comment: !-3 - get's the 3rd item back from now ... !-3:1 get's the first argument from the 3rd item back.

Answer (score 17):

Although I can get around in vi, I use [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) as my [command line editor](http://manual.macromates.com/en/using%5Ftextmate%5Ffrom%5Fterminal.html). You can also pipe things to it. For example **ls|mate** opens up TextMate with the current directly listing open in a text window.

Comment: I've used 'mate .' more times than I care to count.

Comment: Indeed, `mate .` is the best thing ever.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend having a play with Cocoa Emacs.

Answer (score 16):

`mdls` will show you all metadata of the file that Spotlight knows about. You can use the resulting attributes in "mdfind" as well.

`mdutil` allows you to switch indexing on or off on certain volumes, and allows you to reset the index etc.

`systemsetup` is BSD specific (not Mac only), but cool indeed, check its manpage.

`GetFileInfo` (I believe you have to get the developer tools in order to have this) allows you to see all associated times (modification, creation, last accessed) and all attributes of a file.

`automator` allows you to run automator workflows from the command line, while

`osascript` lets you run Apple script code.

Comment: +1 - Didn't know about `automator` good to know ... I suppose ;) - (Generally I use it to run scripts from Finder, so I'm not sure if I'd ever use it the other way around.)

Answer (score 15):

Hit and hold <kbd>esc</kbd> a few seconds to get a list of every possible terminal command on your system, including built-ins, programs on your path, and aliases.

Or, as Martijn pointed out:

Just use <kbd>⇥</kbd> instead, you don't need to hold it for a few seconds even. <kbd>⇥</kbd> will also complete partially typed commands for you, as well as filenames and command-specific arguments.

A prompt asking if you really want to display all command possibilities will appear. Just answer `y` to get the command list.

Comment: Just use <kbd>TAB</kdb> instead, you don't need to hold it for a few seconds even. <kbd>TAB</kdb> will also complete partially typed commands for you, as well as filenames and command-specific arguments.

Comment: If you use Zsh the TAB completion enhancements will rock your world. Try zsh and .oh-my-zsh.

Answer (score 14):

[bcat](http://rtomayko.github.com/bcat/) is a convenient pipe between my always-open terminal (xterm under XQuartz) and my always-open browser.

it sets up a streaming HTTP server for just one process so things like

```
tar czvf - . | tee bcat
```

will just stream until the command exits. Man pages need a bit of cleanup:

```
man bash | col -b | bcat
```

or just

```
export MANPAGER='col -b | bcat'
man bash
```

Answer (score 13):

Auto-complete a command as an argument.
for example start to type:

> which pyt
>   (now press <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>)

it will complete to

> which python

<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> works like tab completion except that it auto-completes using command names instead of file names.

Comment: Looks nice.. Is this supposed to work on Snow Leopard too? It does not work for me..

Answer (score 12):

The more I use it the more addicted to it I am.

```
screen
```

Along with

```
screen -ls
screen -r [session]
```

Very useful for having several screens open on an SSH connection. It saves tons of time especially when you don't have to restart your `tail` everytime you want to check another log file.

Comment: Sadly it's not part of OS X by default but consider tmux. It's basically a better BSD equivalent of GNU screen.

Comment: Strangely on my 10.6.4 OSX, screen exists but tmux does not... I guess I got it via macports - tmux must be a separate install too.

Answer (score 12):

This is my absolute favorite. Sharing screen captures via the internet is a hassle. I wrote this to make sharing screenshots across chat a one step process using DropBox. (I have subsequently come across apps and utilities that do this, but I think this is perfect, at least for me.)

It starts the interactive screenshot utility (same as <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>), saves it your Dropbox's public folder, copies the URL to your clipboard and opens it in your browser.

I run it via LaunchBar, but you could run it from the shell or bind it to a keyboard shortcut to make it as easy as <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>.

You could add something random to the filename if you are worried about privacy.

I used to have it `scp` the screenshot file to my webserver before I switched to Dropbox. You could send the file wherever it would be useful to you. You could even put it in your `~/Sites` directory to use it on your local network.

If you want sign up for dropbox, you can use my [referral link](https://www.dropbox.com/referrals/NTE5MTM3MDE5) which will give us *both* bonus storage. =)

```
#!/bin/sh

# Integrates Mac OS X's screenshot utility with DropBox for easy sharing.

# - Starts the interactive take-screenshot function, saves it to your public
# Dropbox (if you didn't cancel it) where it will be uploaded automatically.
# Copies the public URL to your clipboard and opens your browser to it.

## Config
dropbox_id="112358132134"  ## this is fibonacci's dropbox id
dropbox_public_folder="$HOME/dropbox/Public/screenshots"
upload_delay_in_second=1.5

## Derivative Variables
filename=$(date '+%F__%H-%M-%S.png')
save_to="$dropbox_public_folder/$filename"
url="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/$dropbox_id/screenshots/$filename"

## start interactive screen capture
screencapture -i "$save_to"

## if the screenshot actually saved to a file (user didn't cancel by pressing escape)
if [[ -e "$save_to" ]]; then
    ## echo some output in case you run this in a shell
    echo "Saved screenshot to:" "$save_to"

    ## copy url to the clipboard
    echo "$url" | pbcopy

    ## wait for Dropbox to upload your screenshot, then open in your browser
    sleep $upload_delay_in_second
    ## The `-g` flag means it won't bring your browser to the foreground, which 
    ## feels less like getting interrupted.
    open -g "$url"
fi
```

Comment: This is nice if you want to use DropBox for storage, but almost seems like overkill when considering that Imgur, TinyGrab, and Skitch all have OSX utils.

Comment: That's true, unless you consider those sort of hosts to be temporary and volatile. I don't really know if that's the case anymore, but I like having control of my files.

Comment: Imgur is a much better choice than DropBox. Try this script. http://figbug.com/?page_id=29

Comment: I still like DropBox, but good to know.

Comment: This is already a DB feature.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r Now it is, but it wasn't at the time.

Answer (score 12):

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to active reverse history search. Then start typing a command you've already typed and all matching commands will start presenting to you.

To navigate in the reverse history search simply:

- continue typing to narrow down search
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>: move to the next result
- <kbd>⌫</kbd>: go back to the previous result
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>: cancel your search

eg.

```
apouche:bin>  echo 'type CTRL+R to start reverse search'
(reverse-i-search)`fin': find . -exec grep "MainMenu.nib" {} \;
```

---

*See also the accepted [answer to "How can I search the bash history and rerun a command?"](https://superuser.com/questions/7414/how-can-i-search-the-bash-history-and-rerun-a-command/7416#7416) on Super User.*

Comment: really handy bash command

Answer (score 11):

`diskutil` is a very powerful command-line tool for working with disks and disk images. It's gotten me out of some binds. It's not *too* hard to use.

Answer (score 11):

I’m not sure; this might work in any decent terminal application, not only in OS X’s. However:

Using Terminal.app it is possible to put status information to the actual title bar and not just to the prompt.

In order to do that, you need to change the `PS1` variable in bash to the following model:

```
PS1='\[\033]0;TITLE\007\]PROMPT'
```

Where `TITLE` and `PROMPT` must be substituted to the actual commands which provide the status information. For example, `\w` lists the current full path; `\W` the directory name. You can even execute a command by putting it in backticks. (So you could even put the output of arbitrary commands to the title – or to the prompt.)

Git users (with git’s bash completion installed) might find the following useful. Add this to your `.bashrc`

```
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
PS1='\[\033]0;`__git_ps1` \w\007\]\h:\W \u\$ '
```

and the title bar of Terminal.app will show the current git branch (and whether it’s clean or not) followed by the current full path. This gives useful information about where you are only when you need it and does not make the actual prompt overly long.

In case you don’t use git very much and only care about the path in the title bar:

```
PS1='\[\033]0;\w\007\]\h:\W \u\$ '
```

Comment: What's git's bash completion?

Comment: I'd recommend zsh + .oh-my-zsh (find it on github) has great git completion (and for many other commands too.) - Also has a bunch of prompt themes specifically tailored to show git status in  a git folder.

Comment: As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal also supports setting the tab title separately from the window title. "0" sets both. Use "1" to set the tab title, "2" to set the window title. ("1" technically means "icon title", but Terminal uses it for the tab title, since it doesn't have icon titles in the same sense that xterm and X11 do.)

Answer (score 10):

Print almost any document as a PDF, as long as it has a correctly defined MIME type in OS/X

```
 cupsfilter $filename > output
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to have to say watching Star Wars from the command line is the best:

```
telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl
```

If you say that isn't a command, which it isn't really, just a trick, then I like this:

`defaults write com.apple.dashboard devmode YES`

Comment: No problem, I guess... :)

Comment: this is so epic

Answer (score 8):

Here's a shell function to get the path of the front Finder window. Can be handy. (I started doing this instead of [dragging a folder into the Terminal window.](https://superuser.com/questions/52483/terminal-tips-and-tricks-for-mac-os-x/167512#167512))

```
function fp { osascript -e 'tell application "Finder"'\
 -e "if (${1-1} <= (count Finder windows)) then"\
 -e "get POSIX path of (target of window ${1-1} as alias)"\
 -e 'else' -e 'get POSIX path of (desktop as alias)'\
 -e 'end if' -e 'end tell'; };\

## alias to copy it to the clipboard
alias cfp='fp | pbcopy'
```

(This has been in my zshrc a while, but I don't know where I got it / parts of it, otherwise I'd cite credit.)

Answer (score 8):

Easily burn an ISO from commmand line (with verify burn at the end):

```
hdiutil burn /path/to/iso
```

Without verifying the burn:

```
hdiutil burn -noverifyburn /path/to/iso
```

Answer (score 7):

the most interesting pschotherapist you will ever talk to:

- Run `emacs`
- Press <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- type `doctor` and press enter
- have fun :D

Comment: That's just part of emacs, it's not OS X specific

Comment: wow, this is really fun

Comment: It's hilarious! I love it!

Answer (score 7):

Get a list of airport `SSID`

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -s
```

the `airport` utility has a lot more options to manage the airport configuration. Run without the `-s` to get a list.

Comment: if you tire of long pathnames like this, try `locate airport` - you could run it with `$(locate airport | grep 'Priv')`

Answer (score 6):

alias to open preview from command line

```
alias preview='groff -Tps > /tmp/tmp.ps && open -a Preview /tmp/tmp.ps'
```

So you can do :

```
echo "toto" | preview
cat /tmp/test.log | preview
cheat git | preview
```

Comment: Well, if it respected line-breaks it might even be useful ;)  -- Try `cupsfilter` instead to convert to PDF, it also skips the unnecessary PS-PDF conversion.

Answer (score 6):

Putting a couple of these together, we can get manual pages in a browser with proper markup:

```
bman () {
    gunzip < `man -w $@` | groff -Thtml -man | bcat
}
```

Answer (score 6):

None of these are exactly OSX specific, but here's some stuff from my .bash_profile that I find useful:

Colored Prompt:

```
PS1="\[\e[0;31m\][\[\e[1;31m\]\u\[\e[0;34m\]@\h \[\e[32m\]\w\[\e[0;31m]\]\$\[\e[0m\] ";
```

[example http://grab.by/grabs/c2c7cdff8e49dd764d326620df762665.png](http://grab.by/grabs/c2c7cdff8e49dd764d326620df762665.png)

SSH tab completion of hosts that exist in ~/.ssh/config:  (found on [MacOSXHints](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20100113142633883))

```
complete -o default -o nospace -W "$(/usr/bin/env ruby -ne 'puts $_.split(/[,\s]+/)[1..-1].reject{|host| host.match(/\*|\?/)} if $_.match(/^\s*Host\s+/);' < $HOME/.ssh/config)" scp sftp ssh
```

Highlighted grep:

```
alias grep="grep --color=auto"
```

[highlighted grep http://grab.by/grabs/dd26dd993c74f8dd076e2f911a8e4ec6.png](http://grab.by/grabs/dd26dd993c74f8dd076e2f911a8e4ec6.png)

Automagically dump your public ssh key to a host for future passwordless auth: (can probably easily tweaked to add said host to ~/.ssh/config)

```
ssh-setup() { cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh $1 'cat - >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'; }
```

---

More OSX specific stuff that I've setup forces the machine to take a picture with the built-in iSight every time the machine's lid is open and dumps that image in a directory.
Requirements:

- [SleepWatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/)
- [iSightCapture](http://www.intergalactic.de/pages/iSight.html)

Create a directory somewhere to hold all your images.
Dump this into ~/.wakeup:

```
date=$(date +%y%m%d_%H_%M_%S).jpg;
/PATH/TO/isightcapture -w 640 -h 480 -n 3 -d -t jpg /PATH/TO/PICTURE/DUMP/$date > /dev/null
unset date
```

I've been capping a frame every time my MacBook wakes up for the past 3 1/2 years now, it's interesting to see everything compiled into a long video at a high framerate.

Comment: Your images are broken.

Answer (score 6):

Not installed by default, but [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) is great for adding more command line programs.  After downloading and installing you can use the port command to find and install more programs, plus much more.

```
port search convert video
port install ffmpeg
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you will need to install **XCode** before you can install **MacPorts**.

Comment: And homebrew is much better http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/

Answer (score 6):

My favorite alias:

```
alias redo='sudo \!-1'
```

When you forget to use 'sudo', just do 'redo' to rerun the last command using sudo.

Comment: You can also use !! to mean the last command, so you can do: sudo !!

Comment: if you feel the need to use an alias with more chars than the actual command, consider rewiring your *temporal neocortex*.

Answer (score 6):

Use `!$` to repeat the last parameter in the last command you entered, for example:

```
~$ mkdir test-dir
~$ cd !$
cd test-dir
test-dir$
```

`!$` is actually short for `!!$` which means "from the most recent command, pull the last parameter"

See the "HISTORY EXPANSION" section of the bash man page for more.

Comment: Similarly, there is `!^` for the first command, which I happen to use often.

Comment: `!!` also works fine

Answer (score 6):

```
afplay ~/path/to/file.mp3
```

Let's you play songs from the commandline. You can also append `[space]&` and let it run in the background. :)

Comment: If you were in the tracker/module scene back in the day, you can try [xmp](http://xmp.sourceforge.net/) (compiled Rudix package [here](http://rudix.org/packages/xmp.html)). Then just `xmp ~/path/to/file.mod`.

Answer (score 5):

```
xattr -h
```

allows you to view file attributes.  The most handy use for this command is to remove the internet download warning from the finder:

```
cd /the/directory/where/you/downloaded/all/your/files

xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine .
```

Answer (score 5):

The OSX installer app has a command line interface too.

```
sudo installer -pkg /Volumes/Growl-1.2.1/Growl.pkg -target LocalSystem
```

Is a one line install command for Growl, GrowlNotify is an extra on the same install disk image.

You can find the domains supported by a package file via

```
installer -pkg  /Volumes/Growl-1.2.1/Growl.pkg -dominfo
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a new directory and enter it:

```
md() { mkdir -p "$@" && cd "$@"; }
```

For more, see [my dotfiles repository on GitHub](http://mths.be/dotfiles), and/or [view my `.osx` file for OS X-specific preferences and settings](http://mths.be/osx).

Answer (score 5):

Not a huge feature, but I noticed it wasn't here.

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + mouse drag on Terminal text let's you make a rectangular selection.

Comment: Clarification: It's the "Option" key, not the "Alt" key. It also happens to have an "Alt" label to help people more familiar with Windows, or someone using Windows with an Apple keyboard, including someone using Windows running on a Mac via Bootcamp or a virtualization program like VMware.

Answer (score 5):

```
history|awk '{print $2}'|awk 'BEGIN {FS="|"} {print $1}'|sort|uniq -c|sort -r
```

Gives you a list of some of your most recent commands, numbered by how often you use them.

Answer (score 5):

#### Repeat the previous command with a substring replacement:

*Syntax*:

```
^before^after^
```

*Example*:

You entered:

```
git clonr https://unbelievablylongurl.org/projectdirectory/evenmoreprojects/project.git
```

Use this:

```
^clonr^clone^
```

And your command will be re-run with the replaced substring:

```
git clone http://unbelievablylongurl.org/projectdirectory/evenmoreprojects/project.git
```

Answer (score 4):

```
net rpc shutdown --server=<servername> --username=<username>
```

This will shut down windows boxes.

Comment: This is part of the Samba suite, so not OS X specific.

Answer (score 4):

You can transfer a working directory from one Terminal window to another with these two commands added to your .bash_profile file:

```
alias cwd='pwd | pbcopy'
alias gowd='cd "`pbpaste`"'
```

`cwd` copies your working directory from one window, and `gowd` opens that directory in another window.

Comment: So *that’s* how to make it work. I was always despairing on the `gowd` part …

Answer (score 4):

In my bash profile I have these aliases:

```
# Alias for "." shows current directory
alias -- .='pwd'

# Alias for ".." goes to parent directory
alias -- ..="cd .."
alias -- ...="cd .. ; cd .."
alias -- ....="cd .. ; cd .. ; cd .."
```

Comment: Yeah, me too, working on a shell that doesn't have '..' is strange. :) (FWIW, You could also use `alias '..'='cd ../..'`)

Answer (score 4):

Use Apple’s [ASCIIMoviePlayer](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/ASCIIMoviePlayerSample/Introduction/Intro.html) to play QuickTime movies in the Terminal:

(There are also two great adaptations out there that allow using ANSI colour output).

On a more serious note: CoreImageTool (3rd party; just google for it) is a great way of using CoreImage filters from the command line.

Comment: http://www.entropy.ch/software/macosx/coreimagetool/

Answer (score 4):

```
sips -i *
```

This automagically creates icon previews for all images.

This is better than using the Finder’s “Show icon preview” if you have large files particularly over a server.

Answer (score 4):

drutil does lots of stuff

```
drutil cdtext
```

shows you the cdtext info (if any) on the CD currently in the drive

```
drutil info
```

shows you the capability of your optical drive(s)

```
drutil eject
```

guess what that does

Plus lots more. 'man drutil' to see everything

Answer (score 4):

I have the following aliases and functions in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias ..="cd .."
alias ...="cd .. ; cd .."
alias ls="ls -G" # list
alias la="ls -Ga" # list all, includes dot files
alias ll="ls -Gl" # long list, excludes dot files
alias lla="ls -Gla" # long list all, includes dot files
alias stfu="osascript -e 'set volume output muted true'"
alias pumpitup="sudo osascript -e 'set volume 10'"
alias ips="ifconfig -a | perl -nle'/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/ && print $1'"
alias myip="dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com"
alias flush="dscacheutil -flushcache"
alias gzip="gzip -9n"
alias ping="ping -c 5"
alias ql="qlmanage -p 2>/dev/null" # preview a file using QuickLook

# Create a new directory and enter it
md() { mkdir -p "$@" && cd "$@"; }

# Define a term using Google
define() { local y="$@"; curl -sA "Opera" "http://www.google.com/search?q=define:${y// /+}" | grep -Po '(?<=<li>)[^<]+'|nl|perl -MHTML::Entities -pe 'decode_entities($_)' 2>/dev/null; }

# gzip a file with strongest compression settings
ubergzip() { gzip -9n < "$@" > "$@".gz; }

# Open a man page in Preview.app
pman() { man -t "${1}" | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app; }

# Open a man page in TextMate.app
tman() { MANWIDTH=160 MANPAGER='col -bx' man $@ | mate; }

# Quit an app cleanly
quit() {
    for app in $*; do
        osascript -e 'quit app "'$app'"'
    done
}

# Relaunch an app
relaunch() {
    for app in $*; do
        osascript -e 'quit app "'$app'"';
        sleep 2;
        open -a $app
    done
}

# Uninstall an app with AppZapper
zap() { open -a AppZapper /Applications/"${1}".app; }
```

For more, see [my dotfiles repository on GitHub](http://mths.be/dotfiles), and/or [view my `.osx` file for OS X-specific preferences and settings](http://mths.be/osx).

Answer (score 4):

I often use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to have my Terminal screen cleared instead of UNIX Command `clear`.

The difference is `clear` hides the previous commands from our sight, but we can still scroll back meanwhile <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> clears it completely—we can't scroll back.

I like using it because I can always press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or type:

```
history | grep command-that-I-want-to-do-again
```

if I want to re-type a command without a need to look at "messy character crowded" Terminal.

Comment: There is also Ctrl+L which is a shortcut for `clear`.

Answer (score 4):

In Terminal's Help menu, you can search for man pages. (The first time you do this, it can take a few seconds to index the man page files, so wait a bit for results to appear, but subsequent searches are fast.) It will show man page results in the Help menu search results. Selecting one opens a window displaying the formatted page.

As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, there are a number of enhancements to man page support:

- Man page searching lets you supply section numbers/names in various formats: "2 open", "open 2", "open(2)". It also supports asterisk "*" for wildcard searches.
- It now searches all the files in MANPATH (prior to Lion it only searched a fixed set of directories, so, for example, it didn't find any X11 man pages). It doesn't run in a shell, however, so if you want to customize MANPATH you may need to customize man.conf (x-man-page://1/man), or set it in your [global environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135688/754997).
- There are commands in the Help menu for opening man pages (**Open man Page for Selection**) and performing an apropos search (**Search in man Pages for Selection**). There are corresponding commands in the contextual menu, and there are Services you can enable to perform these lookups from other applications (**System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services > Open man Page in Terminal / Search man Pages in Terminal**).
- If there is no selected text, **Open man Page for Selection** will automatically look at the text to the left of the cursor. This means you can enter a command name, then use this command to open the man page before entering command arguments. It'll skip over whitespace. It also understands man page references "open(2)" and URLs "x-man-page://2/open". (If you explicitly select text, it also understands "2 open" and "open 2".)
- Man page windows use the "Man Page" settings profile. You can customize this to alter the appearance of man pages displayed using these commands. It also remembers the position of man page windows separately from other windows, so you can have man pages appear in the same place on screen each time, independent of where you place other terminal windows.
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+ double-click will open man page references "open(2)", enabling you to navigate references from one man page to another. (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+ double-click will also open any recognized URL, or even some patterns like email addresses—creates a new mail message—and domain names—opens in Safari.)
- When viewing a man page window (or any terminal whose commands have all completed/exited), Terminal supports some "less"-compatible pager commands: <kbd>space</kbd> = <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> = <kbd>Page Up</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd> = <kbd>Page Down</kbd> ("forward"), <kbd>B</kbd> = <kbd>Page Up</kbd> ("back"), <kbd>⌫</kbd> = Scroll down one line, <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> = Scroll up/down one line.

Answer (score 3):

Command line shortcuts to toggle visibility of hidden files in finder:

```
alias show_hidden="defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE && killall Finder"
alias hide_hidden="defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE && killall Finder"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is more a Terminal meta-hint - you can use

```
Cmd-Shift-{Left arrow, Right Arrow}
```

(Command Shift combined with left or right arrow) to quickly cycle between open Terminal.app windows.

Comment: On my Snow Leopard (Belgian keyboard) it's Cmd-Shift-Arrow, not just Cmd-Arrow.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a script that gets the path(s) to the current selection(s) in Finder:

```
#!/bin/sh

osascript` << EOT

tell application "Finder"       
        set theFiles to selection
        set theList to ""
        repeat with aFile in theFiles
                set theList to theList & POSIX path of (aFile as alias) & " "
        end repeat
        theList
end tell

EOT
```

How I use it:

```
$ cat `selected`
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to open a Finder window as the root user, you can execute the following from the terminal:

In 10.5 and below:

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder
```

In 10.6:

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder
```

Then, open a new finder window.
You'll see that the new finder window opens with root permissions.

Comment: When is it useful to open a Finder window as the root user?

Answer (score 3):

Flush the DNS cache if you are editing `/etc/hosts` a lot to test staging servers as looking like production.

```
dscacheutil -flushcache
```

Comment: Use it all the time!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, definitely not mac specific, but TAB completion in `zsh`  is so good I  think it deserves a specific mention.

You get completion of options, e.g.

```
find . -d[TAB]
```

will give you `-daystart`  `-delete` `-depth` as possible completions.

Also path completion is improved over Bash completion, for example, I have a Volume called Wubly, and inside that `video/tv/comedy`, so typing:

```
cd /v/w/v/t/co[TAB]
```

will expand to.

```
cd /Volumes/Wubly/Video/TV/Comedy
```

(note that it's also case insensitive.)

If there are multiple paths that match this pattern, they will be shown.

Completion is also interactive, so you can move around the available choices with the cursor controls.

Answer (score 3):

As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal will open a new window if you drag a folder (or a text pathname) onto the application icon. If you drag to the tab bar of an existing window, it will create a new tab in that window.

You can also do this from the command line or a shell script:

```bsh
open -a Terminal /some/path/
```

This is the command-line equivalent of dragging a folder onto the Terminal application icon and will open a new terminal window at "/some/path".

Terminal also now supports Services for opening a terminal at a selected folder (e.g., in Finder) or a text pathname using the contextual menu. You can enable them in

> System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services

Look for **New Terminal at Folder** and **New Terminal Tab at Folder**. You can even assign command keys to them if you like.

Finally, if you drag a folder or pathname onto an existing tab (i.e., the tab in the tab bar) and the foreground process is the shell, it will execute a "cd" command in one step. As in previous versions, dragging a folder onto the terminal display will insert the pathname to the folder.

Comment: iTerm supports dragging folders onto the icon in 10.6.

Comment: Terminal supported this from long ago

Comment: @Slomojo are you responding to Fake Name or are you trying to correct my statement that Terminal supports this starting in 10.7? (Or did you not notice that I wrote that?)

Comment: @ChrisPage Terminal did this from several versions before 10.7, although I can't currently verify it firsthand before 10.6 (as I don't have a box running older versions) - FYI Cmd-c on a file / folder in Finder and Cmd-v in Terminal will also paste in the full path (same OSX version history.)

Comment: @Slomojo I have confirmed that it did not until 10.7.

Comment: @ChrisPage ... you will need to retract that, it did it in at least 10.5 care for a reference? Here you go http://www.reduser.net/forum/archive/index.php/t-17024.html find David Didato's comment dated 08/10/2008 (10.6 was released in '09) - I also personally used it in Tiger (released '05) and it was taught to me by someone who'd used it in previous versions (10.2 IIRC) - Not to mention I did a live test in 10.6 when I posted my previous comment.

Comment: @Slomojo you’re apparently referring to dragging (or copying and pasting) files from Finder into a terminal window to paste the pathname as if it were entered by the user. This tip/answer is about opening new terminal windows/tabs at a give directory location, which was introduced in 10.7.

Comment: @ChrisPage yes that's what I was referring to, I have obviously shamed myself very badly, and misread the initial comment (I hadn't actually read your tip, and just skimmed it) - Assumed the comment was referring to the drag-drop filename/path feature.  I'll go back in my box now, offering apologies.

Answer (score 3):

If you’re like me, you have multiple Terminal.app tabs open at the same time.

Now, if you open three tabs at the same point in time, then enter some commands in each of them, then close them all, the Bash shell that Terminal.app uses only remembers the command history for the last tab that you close. So, the command history from the other two tabs gets lost.

If you don’t want to lose your command history in any tab, add this to your `~/.bash_profile` (or any other file that gets sourced when a new Terminal tab is opened):

```
# Append to the Bash history file, rather than overwriting it
shopt -s histappend
```

Answer (score 3):

When `cd`ing, one of the most useful features is tab completion.

For example, instead of entering `cd FooBarBazBax`, you can enter `cd FooB` followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Tab completion will work as long as the part of the path or filename you entered isn’t ambiguous.

However, if you were to type `cd foob` followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the completion wouldn’t work, as the folder name starts with an uppercase `F`. Luckily, you can make tab completion even more useful by making it ignore the filename case.

Add this to your `~/.inputrc` file (create the file if you don’t have it already):

```
# Make Tab autocomplete regardless of filename case
set completion-ignore-case on
```

This way, `cd foob` followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd> would complete it into `cd FooBarBazBax`, provided there’s a folder with that name in the current working directory.

Answer (score 3):

Just type

```
purge
```

and it will make inactive memory as free again. Mac OS X keeps apps in memory for a while after you close them, so they will open fast if you open them again. Purge will remove them from memory and give your free memory back.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the system volume automatically too, and kill the screen process afterwards:

```
screen
(hit enter)
sleep 300; osascript -e "set Volume 10"; say "I am feeling fabulous"; open "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"; killall SCREEN
Ctrl-a-d
(detaches)
```

Comment: Why'd this get downvoted - not funny or not appropriate?  Have a sense of humor people!

Comment: What video was that? It's been removed from Youtube.

Comment: So awesome!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Simulate to type Command-F, to fullscreen a video from command line. Useful when launching a movie in mPlayer from ssh.

```
osascript <<END
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "f" using {command down}
END
```

Of course you can also use this trick to simulate any other "typing".

Comment: FYI - iTerm2 has an instant replay function, very useful for making screencasts.

Answer (score 2):

what about

```
cat somefile.txt | say
```

say the contents of a text file...
or...

```
cat someFile.txt | say -o someAudioFile
```

take your text file, convert it to .aiff

Comment: http://sial.org/howto/shell/useless-cat/

Do ``say -o < somefile.txt`` instead

Answer (score 2):

Text file to an Audio file

```
say -o “audiofile.aiff” -f “textfile.rtf”
```

more syntax [here](http://www.trickyways.com/2009/09/convert-text-to-audio-using-mac-terminal/)

Answer (score 2):

Change directory to the directory shown in the top-most Finder window:

```
cdf () {
   currFolderPath=$( /usr/bin/osascript <<-EOT
       tell application "Finder"
           try
               set currFolder to (folder of the front window as alias)
           on error
               set currFolder to (path to desktop folder as alias)
           end try
           POSIX path of currFolder
       end tell
       EOT
   )
   echo "cd to \"$currFolderPath\""
   cd "$currFolderPath"
}
```

---

Another version:

```
f() {
    cd "$(osascript -e 'try
tell app "Finder" to (target of Finder window 1) as text
POSIX path of result
on error
    (system attribute "HOME") & "/Desktop"
end')"
}
```

Comment: Note that in Mac OS X Lion 10.7 and later, Terminal provides a “New Terminal at Folder” service that you can use to open a terminal by selecting a folder and choosing the command from the Finder > Services menu or by Control-Clicking and choosing it from the contextual menu. (You’ll need to enable the service in System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services.) You can also drag a folder onto the Terminal application icon in the Dock, or into a tab bar to create a new tab in an existing window.

Answer (score 2):

Define a term using Google:

```
define() { local y="$@"; curl -sA "Opera" "http://www.google.com/search?q=define:${y// /+}" | grep -Po '(?<=<li>)[^<]+'|nl|perl -MHTML::Entities -pe 'decode_entities($_)' 2>/dev/null; }
```

For more, see [my dotfiles repository on GitHub](http://mths.be/dotfiles), and/or [view my `.osx` file for OS X-specific preferences and settings](http://mths.be/osx).

Answer (score 2):

gzip a file with strongest compression settings:

```
ubergzip() { gzip -9n < "$@" > "$@".gz; }
```

For more, see [my dotfiles repository on GitHub](http://mths.be/dotfiles), and/or [view my `.osx` file for OS X-specific preferences and settings](http://mths.be/osx).

Answer (score 2):

I include all my favorites here:
http://rustyisageek.blogspot.com

Example:

#### Set Volume to 10 and Say something

```
sudo osascript -e "set Volume 10" | say "hello World"
```

#### Wait for network to be ready in a script

```
/usr/sbin/networksetup -detectnewhardware
```

Answer (score 2):

**This is not OSX specific** (`man` says it's from 4.0BSD), but I love it anyways:

```
sudo shutdown -h +45
```

In the above example, `shutdown` shuts down your computer in 45 minutes from now (as one might suspect).

It's great for when you want to spend "just a little bit of time" on your computer before going to bed / doing the dishes / going jogging / whatever. But when you also know deep down that it's not going to be "just a little bit of time"...

Cheers!

Comment: Love `shutdown`!

Answer (score 2):

If you use subversion, opens FileMerge for local checked out files that have been changed.

Requires installation of fmscripts:

```
cd ~/Downloads && svn co http://soft.vub.ac.be/svn-gen/bdefrain/fmscripts && cd fmscripts
sudo make

alias sfmdiff='svn diff --diff-cmd fmdiff'
```

Then in a checked out directory:

```
sfmdiff .
```

(or any specific dir or file)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> will allow you to perform a reverse search within your bash shell.  It's like an interactive form of `history`.

Comment: duplicate of another answer

Answer (score 2):

A relevant command for Terminal.app on Mac OS X is to launch Software Update from the CLI:

```
sudo softwareupdate -i -a
```

The bonus is you do not get any nagging from having to click on windows. I run this as part of a update script that is run every week approximately (so that I do not miss the feedback as it may happen when doing this automatically).

Comment: What does this do when there's an update that requires a restart?

Comment: @JasonSalaz It just prints a message suggesting to restart the OS (but doesn't force a restart or anything).

Comment: using 'softwareupdate -l' is great too just to get a list as well. The Mac App Store in ML doesn't show the size of downloads all the time, but using this tool does.

Answer (score 2):

Quick Look is one of OS X's best features. You just have to press Spacebar in a selected file, and you'll see a preview of that file without having to open up an app. It's great, but you can't select any text when you're in the preview. You can add that feature with a Terminal command:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder QLEnableTextSelection -bool true 
killall Finder
```

Use the feature of Quick Look, select the text you want, and now you could copy it.

Answer (score 1):

Mount iDisk from command line:

```
osascript <<END
tell application "Finder"
mount volume "http://idisk.mac.com/john.doe/" as user name "john.doe" with password "StR0NGP455"
end tell
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Function to make a directory and cd into with a single command:

```
function take {
    mkdir $1
    cd $1
}
```

Comment: Better: `mkdir -p $1`, since this allows creating nested new directories. And putting a `&&` between the commands will only execute `cd` if the folder was successfully created.

Comment: You can also "cd !!:1" where !! is the previous command and :1 takes its (zero-based) argument number. Lets say you do "mv file1 file2" and realize you wanted the opposite: "mv !!:2 !!:1". Of course this is only useful for complex names.

Answer (score 1):

You can browse and search the history by using the cursor keys after adding

```
bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'

bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'
```

to your `.profile`.

Answer (score 1):

open all results of find in a single textmate window:

```
find . -name "pattern"|xargs mate
```

also works with mdfind (spotlight):

```
mdfind -name models.py |xargs mate
```

Comment: you don't need xargs for these, mate will accept STDIN.

Answer (score 1):

Download a URL to the current dir with curl.

```
curl -O http://growl.cachefly.net/Growl-1.2.1.dmg
```

Especially good for downloading source tarballs that Safari wants to decompress for you.

Comment: An alternative is `wget`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `~/.bash_profile`

```
export PS1="\[\e]2;\h - \w\a\e[32;1m\]%\[\e[0m\] "
```

This puts your machine name and current directory in the terminal title bar, so you can keep track of where you are.  This also shows the data in the Window directory.

Answer (score 1):

**Get terminal to open in the last visisted folder:**

I have longed to get terminal to open in the last visited folder, and ended up making a small bash command that accomplishes that. It furthermore allows one to "cd" to a file, which is very helpful when you want to change your directory to that of a given finder file. Simply write *cd*, and drag the file to the terminal and your are there.

Add the following to your .bashrc or .alias file

```
alias cd=mycd

mycd(){ 
  if [ -f "$*" ]
  then
   \cd  "`dirname $*`"
  else 
    \cd "$*";
  fi

  echo "\cd \""`pwd`\""" > ~/.todir  ; 
  PS1='\[\033]0;`pwd | xargs basename`\007\]\e[31m\w:\e[0m
'
}
```

Finally, you need to change your terminal settings:

In terminal:settings:shell - make the shell complete the following command:

```
source ~/.todir; clear
```

Next time you start your terminal - you will automatically be redirected to your last opened directory - the terminal title will change title when you use the *cd* alias, and your prompt will show the full directory path.

Answer (score 1):

As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal supports a few "less"-compatible pager commands when there are no processes running in a terminal. This is useful for paging through and reading text after commands have completed/exited. Supported keys are:

<kbd>space</kbd>:  Page Down
<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>: Page Up
<kbd>⏎</kbd>: Scroll down one line
<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>: Scroll up/down one line
<kbd>F</kbd>: Page down ("forward")
<kbd>B</kbd>: Page up ("back")
<kbd><</kbd>: Home (scroll to top)
<kbd>></kbd>: End (scroll to end)

Terminal has commands that will lookup and display man pages, which these keys are indispensable for viewing. See the Help menu and contextual menus. It also supports Services for opening man pages from other applications (enable them in 
**System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services**).

Answer (score 1):

**LAME encode .wav to .mp3**

This is the original one-liner I used to eventually craft [this handy command](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22803/converting-wav-to-mp3-using-lame-and-automator/22807#22807).

```
find ./ -name "*.wav" -execdir lame -V 3 -q 0 {} \;
```

- Converts 20Mb .wav (at the highest quality settings) to .mp3 in 3
  seconds!
- Simply install the LAME binary and you're golden.

Answer (score 1):

Easy handling of bzip/tar to compress entire directories:

```
# lsZ -- list contents of compressed tar archive
function lsZ() {
    tar tvzf "$1"
}

# deZ -- silently extract contents of compressed tar archive
function deZ() {
    # extract bzip2 compressed tars as well
    if [[ $(file "$1") == *bzip2* ]]; then
        bunzip2 -c "$1" | tar xf -
    else
        tar xzf "$1"
    fi
}

# enZ -- build compressed tar archive
function enZ() {
    tar cZf "${2:-$1.tar.Z}" "$1"
}

# enG -- build compressed tar archive (with gzip)
function enG() {
    tar czf "${2:-$1.tar.gz}" "$1"
}

# enB -- build compressed tar archive (with bzip2)
function enB() {
    tar cf - "$1" | bzip2 > "${2:-$1.tar.bz2}"
}

# lsB -- list contents of bzip2 compressed tar archive
function lsB() {
    bunzip2 -c "$1" | tar tvf -
}

# deB -- silently extract contents of bzip2 compressed tar archive
function deB() {
    bunzip2 -c "$1" | tar xf -
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Silence Idiom - Silence a shell command

You can eliminate the standard output from a verbose command with this shell idiom.

The idiom is:

```
>&-
```

and you use it like this:

```
noisycmd >&-
```

The command runs but nothing is printed to the standard output stream.

Answer (score 1):

**Send Audio to a Apple Tv/Airplay device via the  /usr/bin/say command**

```
/usr/bin/say -r160 -a "AirPlay" "hello world"
```

**-r160** is  Speech rate to be used, in words per minute

**-a**  followed by device *name* or *number*.

Then your text.

To list your available audio device

```
/usr/bin/say -a?
   39 AirPlay
   47 Built-in Output
  209 Soundflower (2ch)
   74 Soundflower (64ch)
```

Using the numbers will work just as well in place of the device name.

```
/usr/bin/say -r160 -a 39 "Hover over a Method";say -r160 -a "Built-in Output" "I am back"
```

You can also use the -f option to use a text file as your speech text.

```
 /usr/bin/say -f ~/Music/foo.txt -r160 -a 39
```

As you will notice say can expand tilde file paths

---

With say you can do a lot more like save speech text directly to audio file.

```
 /usr/bin/say  -o ~/Music/hi.aac Hello, World.
```

**-o** oupt file path.  i.e  ~/Music/hi

**.aac**  file format

This saves a **.acc** file named hi.aac to the Music Directory.

Directory paths MUST exist before the command is run. The file does not need to exist first in the directory and if it does it will most likely be overwritten.

There are other formats you can use.

The man page [say](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/say.1.html) will show you the full list of the options.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted the reverse of the "open ." command, where I could cd to the front Finder window, so I cobbled this together for my .bash_profile:

alias fw='cd "$(osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to POSIX path of (folder of window 1 as string)")"'

Now the "fw" command sets my current directory to the Front Window (for the fw name).

Note that you can type "cd " and then drag the front window to the Terminal to get its path pasted in, then switch to Terminal and hit return.  I think this is easier.  ;)

Comment: Command-Drag will issue the entire `cd` command without any typing.

Answer (score 1):

## Make All Links In Safari Open As New Tabs

New windows, baaad. New tabs, gooood.
In general, Safari’s tab controls are wonderful, but one failing drives us crazy: Certain links are allowed to override your preference for opening new webpages in tabs, essentially forcing the application to open a new window. To prevent this in the future, execute this command: `defaults write com.apple.Safari TargetedClicksCreateTabs -bool TRUE`.

---

## Show Hidden Files in The Finder

The names of hidden files always begin with a period--keep that in mind before you delete or edit a file that doesn’t look familiar.
Believe it or not, the files you see listed on your Desktop in the Finder do not represent all of the files contained in your Desktop folder. In almost every folder, the OS hides system files that Apple considers too important for the likes of us to mess with (or too mundane for us to be bothered with). Now and again, though, it’s useful to view these files. To see the full contents of all folders in the Finder, execute :  `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE`.

---

## Disable the Dashboard

When the Dashboard appears on our Desktop, it’s usually because we missed the delete key and hit F12 instead.
We’ve always liked the Dashboard in theory--on occasion, we’ve even downloaded widgets for it. Unfortunately, we never get around to using them, and our aging Mac laptop could use the extra RAM to run real apps. If you’re in the same boat, free up some system memory by terminating the Dashboard with two quick Terminal commands. First, set its default to Off by executing : `defaults write com.apple.dashboard mcx-disabled -boolean YES`. Second, kill and restart the Dashboard and Dock with this command: `killall Dock`.

---

## A lot more on this website : [Click HERE](http://www.maclife.com/article/feature/terminal_tips_every_mac_usershould_know)

Answer (score 1):

*pg* with no arguments ping the IP 8.8.8.8 (usefull for basic internet connection test), otherwise ping the given IP. If the IP is incomplete, it is concat with the default prefix 192.168.1 allowing easy local ping (eg ping 3.12 => 192.168.3.12)

```
function pg() {
    ip4regex='^[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+$'
    ip3regex='^[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+$'
    ip2regex='^[0-9]+[.][0-9]+$'
    ip1regex='^[0-9]+$'
    host=$@
    if [[ $# == 0 ]]; then
        host="8.8.8.8"
    elif [[ $@ =~ $ip4regex ]]; then
        host="$@"
    elif [[ $@ =~ $ip3regex ]]; then
        host="192.$@"
    elif [[ $@ =~ $ip2regex ]]; then
        host="192.168.$@"
    elif [[ $@ =~ $ip1regex ]]; then
        host="192.168.1.$@"
    fi
    ping $host
}
```

Comment: here is the corresponding gist: https://gist.github.com/MartinDelille/9386306

Answer (score 0):

Add a file named "-i" to your home directory. Now if you accidentally type:

```
rm -rf *
```

it will expand to:

```
rm -rf -i your other files
```

and you will be prompt to confirm or deny the removal of the entire dir. It's pretty hacky, but it's saved my butt before.

Comment: just alias rm to rm -i : `alias rm='rm -i'`

Answer (score 0):

I find it useful to copy text to the clipboard from Terminal.app without using the mouse to make a selection.

This seems to only works with the older Terminal.app from Tiger.  I just renamed it to Tiger Terminal.app, and it still runs fine on Leopard.  Haven't tried it on Snow Leopard.

So, with Tiger Terminal, you can do mouse-free copy by typing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd>, then using the arrow keys to move to the start of the area you want to copy.  Next, type <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd> again to anchor the selection point.  Use the arrow keys (some emacs-like commands also work for navigation like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) to move to the end of the region you want to copy.  Finally, type <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd> again to copy selection to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

BBEdit version for viewing man pages:

```
bbman () {
  MANWIDTH=160 MANPAGER='col -bx' man $@ | bbedit --clean
}
```

Answer (score 0):

List all directories alone in a directory - er - folders in a folder.

```
ls -la | grep '^d'
```

Find sizes of given directory - again - er - folder.

```
du -s dirname
```

Answer (score 0):

user42053 mentions adding a file `-i` to every folder. Gets a bit hairy seeing `-i` in every folder everywhere else. Easier method would be

```
alias rm="rm -i"
```

Comment: This is a baaaaad idea since you'll get too used to this, what if you're on a system without it and you do a careless `rm -rf`?

Answer (score 0):

Drag the proxy icon of a Finder window to get an escaped path; especially useful after typing `cd`

Comment: or drag it and do `C-a` `cd` `RETURN`

Comment: On Mac OS X Lion 10.7 and later, you can drag a folder (or a proxy icon, or a pathname selected in text) onto the Terminal application icon to create a new terminal window at that location. There are also “New Terminal at Folder” and “New Terminal Tab at Folder" Services you can enable (in System Preferences), which will show up in the contextual menu when selecting folders or pathnames. You can also drag onto an existing terminal tab to automatically issue a cd command, and you can drag onto the blank area of the tab bar to create a new tab at that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I made an alias called dirstat, named for a similar utility.  It helps determine where all the hard drive space is being used.  Add it to your `/etc/bashrc` or as a bash script.

```
du -s ./* | sort -n| cut -f 2-|xargs -i du -sh {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Automatically update the Terminal.app window title to display your username, host and current directory.

If I do the following:

```
cd ~/Developer
```

I want the Terminal window title to be updated to:

```
jason@rocksteady:~/Developer
```

To achieve this, make sure that the PROMPT_COMMAND variable is set in your ~/.bash_profile:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/#$HOME/~}"; echo -ne "\007"'
```

Of course, you can substitute whatever suits your fancy.

Comment: As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal supports setting the window and tab (icon) titles separately. "0" sets them both. Use "1" to set the tab title, "2" to set the window title.

Answer (score 0):

I've added the lines below to my `~/.bash_profile` file.

With the <kbd>⇥</kbd> you will see the effect by starting a command/path and hitting <kbd>⇥</kbd> a few times.

Change function of <kbd>⇥</kbd> to scroll through autocomplete options:

```
bind '"\t":menu-complete'
```

SSH as root to...:

```
alias shroot="ssh -l root"
```

Force eject volumes:

```
alias forceeject="hdiutil detach -force"
```

Force quit an application:

```
alias forcequit="killall -HUP"
```

Open man pages as PDFs:

```
pdfman() { man $1 -t | open -f -a Preview; };
```

Alias pingburst:

```
alias ping2="ping -c2"
```

Comment: -1 Please just format commands using the 4 space indent.

Answer (score 0):

Set bash to exit a script immediately on any error.

```
set -o errexit
```

Always a good idea when developing bash scripts, especially destructive ones.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to open and close DMGs is:

```
open <My disk image>.dmg
```

Then to close it:

```
umount /Volumes/<My disk image>
```

Comment: if you use umount like that, you'll leave the `/Volumes/<My disk image>` folder lying around. Use `diskutil eject /Volumes/<My disk image>` instead, it'll clean up after you.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a network volume, you could use `mkdir`;`mount` and `umount`;`rmdir` etc, etc... however that's long-winded and there's a better Mac specific alternative method...

You can open a share:

```
open afp://user:pass@server/sharepointname
```

and eject it with:

```
diskutil eject /Volumes/sharepointname
```

By the way, you can also open a dialog to select from a list of all the sharepoints on a server by doing..

```
open afp://user:pass@server/
```

Omit the user/password to prompt for credentials in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

```
drutil eject
drutil tray eject # analagous to above
```

Opens the CD tray or ejects a CD (for a laptop)

```
drutil tray close
```

Closes the CD tray

These are very useful when you are SSHing into another computer.

Comment: So how is this useful? Can you ssh the CD to the tray? You do still have to get up and go to the machine to get a CD or place something in the now open tray.

Comment: @bmike Very true.

Comment: I've used `drutil eject` before to eject a disk from the SuperDrive I removed from my MacBook Pro and placed in an external enclosure. Sometimes the OS doesn't recognize that the enclosure is connected and doesn't respond to the eject button making this command very useful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>esc</kbd> key as replacement for alt. >ou have to tap it first and then enter the other instead of holding it. It's a standard feature, but more important as the <kbd>⌥</kbd> key on macs works different as on "windows/Linux" keyboards.

You can set the behavior of alt key in preferences to behave like on "windows" keyboards. Though you then will be unable to type important characters as @, \, {, ...

Very important if you use emacs in terminal. But suppose there are many commands that require it - eg you can also copy-paste in bash with emacs bindings.

Comment: A couple points of clarification: The name of the modifier key is “Option”. (It also has “alt” printed on the key to indicate that when you’re using the keyboard with Windows it will perform the same function as “Alt”.) Option is only needed to type characters like “{“ and “}” on certain physical keyboard layouts, e.g., French. It is not used in US English keyboard layouts, for example.

Answer (score 0):

One I actually use quite a lot is `uptime`. Simple but nice :) Currently mine returns `up 32 days, 14:30`.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly from one Terminal window to itself or another Terminal window:

**Select text** in the normal way, then paste it by moving the mouse to the window you want to paste into, and clicking the **middle mouse button**.

Note that if you have made multiple selections with Command-Option drags, pasting will paste in a newline, which will invoke the current line. This is **probably not something you want**.

Answer (score 0):

### Local Web Server with Ruby

Here is the Ruby alternative to the Python one-liner for a local HTTP server (that is also posted in this thread):

```
ruby -run -e httpd . -p 8000
```

This will open a server in the working directory with a port number of 8000 so that you can access it in the browser at `http://localhost:8000`.

Change the 8000 to any port number that you would like to use.

Answer (score 0):

Many answers have been given about how you can drag files and folders into the terminal window but Ciarán Walsh has made a utility called [drag](https://github.com/ciaran/drag) that allows you to drag files OUT of the terminal window. It’s even better with my [patch](https://github.com/ciaran/drag/pull/1) that allows multiple files per drag operation.

Answer (score 0):

I could not believe that the following is missing here. The best improvement of a OS X terminal is to make it feel UNIX/Linux like. My first intention was to show you a proper `bash-completion` completing several things like `ssh` or `git` correctly. I'm talking of standard behaviour I was used to from Linux.

But much more important is the missing package manger [homebrew](http://brew.sh). With this you will get plenty of standard unix commands/apps/libraries.

First install [homebrew](http://brew.sh) via

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

and then get the sophisticated bash-completion via

```
brew install bash-completion
```

Dont ignore the message. You will have to edit `.bash_profile`. But its worth it. `bash-completion` completes `brew` too.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+D is a shortcut for exit. Useful if you often work in nested `ssh` sessions.

Answer (score 0):

It's been mentioned already that dragging a folder into a terminal app will get the path typed directly in it. You can additionally drop a folder onto the terminal app icon and a new terminal will be opened in that path directly

Answer (score 0):

While a top already mentions option (alt)-click to move to a position in the line, in reality this works anywhere in the terminal. I use it most prominently in text editors.

Anywhere you can get by arrow-ing alt-click will get the cursor there as well.

This is the main reason I stopped using tabs in code in the early 90s, NCSA Telnet included this functionality back then for mac's System 7 and if tried to arrow its way through tabs, so it ended up going all over the place and beeping like crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I use a lot this command

```
echo | pwd | pbcopy
```

It's simply copy current path to clipboard. I've also binded it with path alias

```
alias path='echo | pwd | pbcopy'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add aliases for phrases that you commonly mistype

```
alias sdou='sudo'
alias suod='sudo'
alias sodu='sudo'
alias gerp='grep'
```

Answer (score -1):

Useless, but fun. Go and download the [ASCII players](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0B-OdXAaH4479OWRjYzE0MDAtYmY0Mi00ZDA2LWI4OWYtNThlYmUyZjM0MmJl&hl=en) from Google Docs. Install them in `/usr/bin`. Now you can have a movie player in Terminal. There is `ASCIIbw` and `ASCIIcolor`. I don't think I need to explain that one is color and one is black and white. To open a movie file type: `ASCIIbw ~/Desktop/Test.mov`

Comment: Wow. Thank you Google for doing what `aalib` and `libcaca` never could. Making a sensible interface to just do what I want.

Comment: Or whoever made them. Perhaps not Google.

Comment: @VxJasonxV I don't remember who made them. I uploaded them to my Google Docs so I have a copy of them somewhere.

Comment: Oh, that's your upload. Cool. The color one is broken BTW, it is built for PowerPC, no Intel.

Answer (score -1):

```
alias ka="killall"
```

Probably one of my most used commands. I put this in my `.bash_profile` for easy access.

Answer (score -1):

When I'm in terminal I expect every action to be given in written form, because there is no GUI.

Many of the terminal based apps have some kind of quit command to bring you back to shell. This is what I'm used to when in terminal.

To leave a terminal window or tab I aliased following command:

```
alias q="osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to tell process \"Terminal\" to keystroke \"w\" using command down'"
```

### EDIT:

better even is to do as Jason commented:

configure Terminal.app to close the window if the shell exited cleanly

```
alias q="logout"
```

Comment: Configure your terminal to close shell when existed cleanly, and then: `alias q="logout"`.

Comment: There’s no need to simulate a Command-W key press. Just tell Terminal to close the tab or window, e.g.: `tell application "Terminal" to close the front window`

Comment: Hey yeah, Jason, thats better indeed. Had no idea about that terminal preference.

@Chris: Im not that good at applescript so forgive me for my ignorance.

Answer (score -1):

If you have XCode installed, running the command `purge` at the terminal is really helpful.  It frees up all of your active and inactive RAM.  It's useful for people like me who do a lot of audio production (or any kind of media editing for that matter) when you only have 4 GB RAM.  You would be surprised how fast 4 GB gets used up.

Answer (score -3):

```
alias alias_open="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/aliases.zsh"
alias alias_reload="source ~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/aliases.zsh"
alias lsa='ls -lahG'
alias l='ls -la'
alias ll='ls -l'
alias sl=ls # often screw this up
alias ..='cd ..'
alias ...='cd ../..'
alias ....='cd ../../..'
alias .....='cd ../../../..'
alias ......='cd ../../../../..'

#######
# GIT #
#######
alias gd="git diff"
alias gl="git log"
alias gu="git up"
alias gs="git status"
alias gf="git fetch"
alias gr="git remote -v"
alias gp="git push"
alias gph="git push heroku master"
alias gps="git push staging staging:master"
alias gpg="git push github master"
alias gpo="git push origin master"
alias gplh="git pull heroku master"
alias gpls="git pull staging staging:master"
alias gplg="git pull github master"
alias gplo="git pull origin master"
alias gpl="git pull"
alias gc="git commit -am"
alias gco="git checkout"
alias ga="git add ."

##########
# SYSTEM #
##########
alias cwd='pwd | pbcopy' #copy the working directory into the clipboard
alias grep="grep --color=auto"

####################################################
# Create box of '#' characters around given string #
####################################################

function box() { t="$1xxxx";c=${2:-#}; echo ${t//?/$c}; echo "$c $1 $c";echo ${t//?/$c}; }

########################
# Rip audio from video #
########################

# ("$1" for output file & "$2" for input file)
function audioextract()
{
mplayer -ao pcm -vo null -vc dummy -dumpaudio -dumpfile "$1" "$2"
}
# extract audio from DVD VOB files
# USAGE:  audioextractdvd input_file.vob output_file.ac3
function audioextract_dvd()
{
mplayer "$1" -aid 128 -dumpaudio -dumpfile "$2"
}

#######################
# Backup .bash* files #
#######################

function backup_bashfiles()
{
  ARCHIVE="$HOME/bash_dotfiles_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).tar.gz";
  cd ~
  tar -czvf $ARCHIVE .bash_profile .bashrc .bash_functions .bash_aliases .bash_prompt
  echo "All backed up in $ARCHIVE";
}
```

Comment: I think the reason why you got downvotes on this was because you didn't explain what each of the aliases does.