# Is there a beginners guide to Unix from the OS X point of view?

Tags: terminal, unix

I'm hoping to build on my embarrassingly-limited knowledge of the command line, and I know there are a ton of great resources out there. I'm wondering if there are any books or other resources that are tailored specifically to the OS X user running Terminal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there is always [Apple´s official command line guide](https://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/10.8/#apd16A67EB8-B25D-4693-9428-372FAB112A4A) but back when I learned my way around the Terminal, I found [Unix for the beginning Mage (PDF, free)](http://unixmages.com/) quite entertaining *and* educational (given it suits your humour).

If you´d rather go for a book, I´d highly recommend ["The Mac OS X Command Line: Unix Under the Hood"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0782143547).

Comment: Two years later: [Apple's command line guide has moved](https://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/10.8/#apd16A67EB8-B25D-4693-9428-372FAB112A4A)

Comment: https://www.hugedomains.com/domain_profile.cfm?d=unixmages&e=com no longer reachable

Comment: @Mozak a quick search [returns this PDF](https://lab46.g7n.org/_media/haas/ufbm.pdf) which seems right to me, but I'm afraid this link could die soon, too. Also keep in mind my answer is now more than a decade old ;-)

Comment: Noted @Asmus. I will check the PDF shared. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This [Mac OS X Unix Tutorial](http://osxfaq.com/Tutorials/LearningCenter/) has a lot of information in there which you could start from. All in all, I think that if you start up with any of the good resources on Linux (or Unix), you should be able to get up to speed with most aspects of Unix on OS X.

Answer (score 3):

O'Reilly has several [Learning UNIX for Mac OS X](http://search.oreilly.com/?q=learning+unix+for+mac+os+x) books. They were all published several years ago, and the most recent one is for Tiger. But they are still relevant to UNIX, as one of the great things about UNIX is that the fundamentals are quite stable.

Comment: I've got the Tiger edition of the book.  While UNIX is relatively stable, some of the OS X specific features change quite a bit between OS X releases.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a fan of [Take Control of the Mac Command Line with Terminal](http://www.takecontrolbooks.com/command-line), by Joe Kissell. It's a $10 ebook that is specifically designed for beginning command line users on Mac OS X. I think it's exactly what you asked for. I find many O'Reilly UNIX books to be frustratingly opaque for the beginner.

Book blurb from the above link:

> If you've ever thought you should
>   learn how to use the Unix command line
>   that underlies Mac OS X, or felt at
>   sea when typing commands into
>   Terminal, Joe Kissell is here to help!
>   This 111-page ebook will help you
>   become comfortable working on the
>   Mac's command line, starting with the
>   fundamentals and walking you through
>   more advanced topics as your knowledge
>   increases. And if you're uncertain how
>   to put your new-found skills to use,
>   Joe includes numerous real-life
>   "recipes" for tasks that are best done
>   from the command line.

Disclaimer: Though I wrote a [Take Control book](http://www.takecontrolbooks.com/entourage-2004) seven years ago, I have no financial interest in Joe's book.

Answer (score 3):

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/tutoriallist has reviews of some bash tutorials for beginners. The highest rated one is http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide.

OS X-centered lists of shell commands:

- http://www.leftcolumn.net/2009/02/15/40-useful-mac-os-x-shell-scripts-and-terminal--commands
- [http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5435/got-any-tips-or-tricks-for-terminal-in-mac-os-x](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5435/got-any-tips-or-tricks-for-terminal-in-mac-os-x)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/7346/what-are-useful-command-line-commands-on-mac-os-x

More advanced resources:

- /usr/share/doc/bash/bash.html and /usr/share/doc/bash/bashref.html
- Stack Exchange API, like https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users#pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&ids=22565&filter=!-079JKuzWRrc&site=unix&run=true
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls
- http://lri.me/shell.txt and http://lri.me/shell.html
- http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/browse/last-month/sort-by-votes
- https://twitter.com/climagic

Answer (score 2):

There is this kid on youtube who runs the macheads channel - best place to start learning the terminal is his 21 part series - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OaIBH4fNqOc

Another source I would point to is the Meet the Command Line series by Dan Benjamin at Peepcode: http://peepcode.com/products/meet-the-command-line

Answer (score 2):

I have a newsletter and upcoming screencast specifically for OS X users, which you can follow here: 
http://learning-the-unix-command-line-on-os-x.chipcastle.com/

Comment: Is there a newsletter archive?

Comment: Not yet, because the first issue was sent this morning, which you can find here: http://us7.campaign-archive2.com/?u=fd1f24aadaae48b22d7d03a3b&id=fd7c6dc6c1&e=eea0aeb2d0

Comment: There is also my course on Udemy https://www.udemy.com/learning-the-unix-command-line-on-os-x/.