# Prompt command on MacBook

Tags: macos, command-line

I just broke a computer with Windows system and I bought a MacBook but I don't know how can I open prompt command in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application "Terminal" can be found under `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal`.

You can also easily find and open files and applications using Spotlight:

- Command + Space Bar (to open Spotlight search)
- Start typing "Terminal"
- Hit Enter when terminal is found

That is a really handy move I use to open almost everything.

---

Update:

Helpful links for Shell/Bash beginners can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/9989/210491).

Answer (score 0):

It is the app called `Terminal`.

By default this is located in Applications > Utilities > Terminal.