# Listing the terminal commands available for Mac OS

Tags: terminal

I would like to make more use of the terminal. Is there a command I can use that could list for me all the available command of the Mac OS? I am using Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can hold the esc button for a few seconds (or press it or tab twice in succession). That will list everything executable in the path as well as all shell functions.

Also check out this question: [Got any tips or tricks for Terminal in Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5435/terminal-tips-and-tricks-for-mac-os-x).

This is a good introduction: [Introduction to the OS X Unix Command Line](http://www.matisse.net/OSX/intro_unix/0_outline.html).

If you type `apropos .*`, you will get a nice list of command and descriptions.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I am curious, why is holding the esc button for a few seconds displays all the commands (all 1979 of them:), isn't it an odd way to show them?

Comment: Its a form of autocompletion.  Similar to if you press any letter and then hold esc it will show you all the command starting with that letter.  You can also type apropos .*  and it will give you a nice list ;)

Comment: I didn't know apropos had wildcarding/regex. Awesome.

Comment: Instead of holding Esc, you can just press it, or Tab, twice.

Comment: this depends on which shell you are using

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to read a command line introduction from Apple: "[Command Line Primer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/CommandLine/CommandLine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001067-CH271-BBCBEAJD)"

Answer (score 1):

One way to find new commands is via manual pages.

For example `man cd` will take you to the man page on the `cd` command.

At the bottom of the manual page is a "see also" section.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a site recently that has a good list of commands:

[ss64.com/osx/](http://ss64.com/osx/)

A few very interesting commands listed there that I had never seen before (though not documented only, use `man *commandname*` locally if necessary):

`dsenableroot`
`dot_clean`
`kextfind`, and
`security`

Many of the commands listed on the site are not OS X specific, but a few gems in there are, including the above.