# Can my Mac tell jokes?

Tags: macos, mac, software

Sometimes I just need a break from serious work. Can my Mac OS install tell me any jokes?

Comment: you might want to remove the word "good" from your sentence...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why yes, it can, as a matter of fact. Follow [these steps](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/having-a-conversation-with-your-mac-computer/) to hear some high quality jokes on your Mac.

- Open up Speech Recognition in your system settings.
- Enable "Speakable Items"
- Enable "Speak Command Acknowledgement"

Set up the rest however you like (in regards to key press or keyword for input). When you're ready, say "Tell me a joke." (Or, if you have a keyword " tell me a joke".)

Enjoy! (Tested in Lion, although this has been around for quite some time.)

Comment: Has been around since System 7 when Macintalk was introduced. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely recall a way to see (not hear) a joke in Terminal … maybe from before Mac OS X.

I paged through [Got any tips or tricks for Terminal in Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/5435/8546) but can't find anything relating to jokes …