# What files are accessed when an app starts up?

Tags: settings, startup, preferences

I am wondering if there is a way to see which files an application accesses (reads or writes) when starting up.

`/usr/bin/fs_usage` seems like one tool, but I wondered if there are others.

I am trying to make it easy to copy preferences between two computers, and I figured that this was one step approaching that goal, but I'm interested in the question for several reasons. I know preferences are usually kept in `~/Library/Preferences/` and `~/Library/Application Support`, but how do I find out which files/folders specifically?

Comment: A related question posted yesterday: [How can I see where a program writes to my disk? - Apple - Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34370/how-can-i-see-where-a-program-writes-to-my-disk).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's a couple of options. You could use a `launchd` script with a `WatchPaths` property that triggers on those directories.

You can also use the command-line tool `lsof` to list open files of a process.

You can inspect open files per-process using `Activity Monitor`. If you click on the process and click "Inspect", it should bring up additional information. One of the tabs here should be for open files (see below).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

When I'm curious about things like this, I immediately turn to [fseventer](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart). It is essentially a GUI for fs_usage, and simply presents a list of files as they're being modified/created/deleted. In the default tree view mode, you good a nice hierarchy of files modified and their paths. In tree view, you can hover over a file or directory with a red (i) icon over it and see which application touched it.

Over in the second tab (grid mode), you can easily see which files were modified by an application. Screenshots of each of these are on [fseventer's homepage](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart).

There are a lot of nice options to tailor the output to exactly what you need, such as when (if ever) files should disappear from the list, various output views, and a few more nice-to-haves.

fseventer is free, donations-suggested; some people call it "nag-ware" because you have to dismiss a donation dialog on application start.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is the `opensnoop` DTrace script. It traces file opens and can show various details, like time (`-v`) and error codes (`-e`). You can also restrict snooping to a particular process (`-n` or `-p`). The man page (run `man opensnoop`) has all the details.